# Recursive type-specific control enable.state setting

Tags: vb.net, controls

I'm trying to build a quick sub that will disable all controls of a given type `T` on a form and within any containers on that form, such as within a `GroupBox`

The code I have currently (below) annoyingly seems to ignore GroupBox controls for some reason (and I realise I have only tried it with a `Form` container otherwise yet, for which it does work).

```
Private Sub ChangeControlEnabledState(Of T As Control)(cc As ContainerControl, state As Boolean)
    Dim cl As ControlCollection = cc.Controls
    For Each c As Object In cc.Controls ' Iterate through every object in the container
        If TypeOf c Is T Then   ' Check if the object matches the type to set the state on
            CType(c, T).Enabled = state ' Set the state on the matching object
        ElseIf TypeOf c Is ContainerControl Then    ' Check if the object is a "sub" container type
            ChangeControlEnabledState(Of T)(c, state)   ' Recurse to handle the controls within the "sub" container
        End If
    Next
End Sub

'Usage
ChangeControlEnabledState(Of Button)(Me, False) 'Changes all buttons on this form to Button.Enabled = false
```

Maybe `GroupBox` is not a `ContainerControl`?

EDIT:
Adjusted to this:

```
        For Each c As Control In cc ' Iterate through every object in the container
            If TypeOf c Is T Then   ' Check if the object matches the type to set the state on
                CType(c, T).Enabled = state ' Set the state on the matching object
            ElseIf c.HasChildren Then  ' Check if the control has children
                ChangeControlEnabledState(Of T)(c.Controls, state)   ' Recurse to handle the child controls
            End If
        Next
```

But this throws an exception on the first `GroupBox` when attempting to recurse:

> System.InvalidCastException   {"[A]ControlCollection cannot be cast to [B]ControlCollection. Type A originates from 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'. Type B originates from 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' in the context 'Default' at location 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Windows.Forms\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Windows.Forms.dll'."}  System.InvalidCastException

Which to my limited understanding seems to say that a cast from type X cannot be made to type X because it is type X...

Comment: I've tried changing to `ElseIf (c.GetType).GetField("Controls") IsNot Nothing Then ...` but no dice.

Comment: Turn on Option Strict and dont box the loop iterator

Comment: @Plutonix Think that's what my father used to say if I was getting on his nerves :p
But otherwise Im afraid I dont know what that means

Comment: `Control.ControlCollection` instead of `ControlCollection` for the Sub parameter type does the trick for the exception. 
Silly generic objects that aren't generic except for when they're generic. But sometimes they're still not... grumpy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this will help, but I use control.haschildren to determine the recursive call.

```
Private Sub SetEnterHandler(ByVal ParentCtrl As Control)
    'recursive call to find all controls that can have focus
    For Each c As Control In ParentCtrl.Controls
        If c.HasChildren Then
            SetEnterHandler(c)
        Else
            'do non-container stuff here
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

I call this sub from an initializing sub:

```
    For Each c As Control In Me.Controls
        If c.HasChildren Then SetEnterHandler(c)
    Next
```

Where Me is the form.

Comment: OK, that helps Identify if there are child controls perfectly, now I just have to be able to convert the parent control to some generic that takes any parent control (not just a `ContainerControl`, which it turns out is *not* any control that contains controls). Will I have to go as generic as `Control` or is there any type tighter than that that covers all controls that can have child controls?

Comment: No, I think control is about as tight as you can go.

Comment: Private Sub ChangeControlEnabledState(Of T As Control)(cc As Control, state As Boolean)

        For Each c As Control In cc.Controls
            If TypeOf c Is T Then
         CType(c, T).Enabled = state
     ElseIf c.HasChildren Then
         ChangeControlEnabledState(Of T)(c, state)
     End If
 Next
    End Sub

Answer (score 1):

This error is because `ContainerControl` is defined in `Control` Class in "`System.Windows.Forms`" namespace and it is parent class for forms and any controls.
All child classes from `Control` are producing their own ControlCollection class which is not really needed.

Just use `Control.ContainerControl` to explicit definition and this error will disappear!